# IOS Swift Service Characteristics

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth device (Adafruit Flora BLE) and looking for characteristic data to attach notification callbacks to. Problem is, I'm not seeing any characteristics listed. All I see are properties of the service itself and no characteristics.

Here is some code that shows where the identification of device and looking for service is occurring. Pardon the spaghetti code, just debugging/hacking together a prototype right now.

Basically, I'm trying to set up a notifier to the BLE service on the arduino/flora module so that I can send via UART sensor data. I have all the connection working, but can't seem to get the listener and updating portion working. Thanks!

```
func startScanning() {
    print("Started scanning.")
    visiblePeripheralUUIDs.removeAllObjects()
    visiblePeripherals.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    tableView.reloadData()
    manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    scanTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("stopScanning"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

---

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

    let UUID = "818ECB19-BB61-BE95-2D04-64E5D90845EF";

    if (peripheral.identifier.UUIDString == UUID){


       // print("Peripheral found with name: \(peripheral.name)\nUUID: \(peripheral.identifier.UUIDString)\nRSSI: \(RSSI)\nAdvertisement Data: \(advertisementData)")
        visiblePeripheralUUIDs.addObject(peripheral.identifier.UUIDString)
        visiblePeripherals[peripheral.identifier.UUIDString] = Peripheral(peripheral: peripheral, RSSI: RSSI.stringValue, advertisementDictionary: advertisementData)
        tableView.reloadData()
        //
        connectedPeripheral = peripheral
        connectionAttemptTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("timeoutPeripheralConnectionAttempt"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        manager.connectPeripheral(connectedPeripheral!, options: nil)

    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    //print("Peripheral connected: \(peripheral.name ?? peripheral.identifier.UUIDString)")
    connectionAttemptTimer?.invalidate()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let peripheralViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeripheralViewController") as! PeripheralViewController
    peripheralViewController.peripheral = peripheral
    navigationController?.pushViewController(peripheralViewController, animated: true)

    print("--------Starting service discovery")

//        print("!!!!!!!!!!Services be present \(peripheral.services?.count)");
//        for service in (peripheral.services)! {
//            print("SERVICES: \(service)")
//        }
    }
```

---

```
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
    print("GOT TO PERIPHERAL")

    if (peripheral != self.peripheral) {
        // Wrong Peripheral
        print("WrONG PERIPHERAL")
        return
    }

    if (error != nil) {
        print(" GOTS US AN ERROR")
        return
    }

    print("CHECKING ON CHARACTERISTICS \(service.UUID)")


//        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
//            print("CHARACTERISTIC \(characteristic)")
//            if characteristic.UUID == service2 {
//                print("WHAT THE F*** BRO \(characteristic as CBCharacteristic)");
//                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
//                
//                // Send notification that Bluetooth is connected and all required characteristics are discovered
//                //self.sendBTServiceNotificationWithIsBluetoothConnected(true)
//            }
//        }
    }
```

---

Updated the didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService and it's still not returning anything for me to parse in my for loop:

```
`func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
        print("GOT TO PERIPHERAL")

    if (peripheral != self.peripheral) {
        // Wrong Peripheral
        print("WrONG PERIPHERAL")
        return
    }

    if (error != nil) {
        print(" GOTS US AN ERROR")
        return
    }

    print("What is service:  \(service)")
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        print("CHARACTERISTIC \(characteristic)")
        if characteristic.UUID == service2 {
            print("WHAT THE F*** BRO \(characteristic as CBCharacteristic)");
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)

            // Send notification that Bluetooth is connected and all required characteristics are discovered
            //self.sendBTServiceNotificationWithIsBluetoothConnected(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something stupid here?

Christian

Comment: After `print("--------Starting service discovery")`, you need to do call `discoverServices:`. It should trigger `peripheral:
didDiscoverServices:` then call `discoverCharacteristics:forService:` which should trigger `peripheral: didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:`.

Comment: Pasted updated code above:

Comment: You didn't call `discoverServices:` on `peripheral` in `centralManager: didConnectPeripheral:`

Comment: Sorry, for the sake of brevity, I left that change out, but I did call it. I get to the following: 

the following callback does execute: func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) 

Within that callback, I run:

for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            if characteristic.UUID == service1 { 
.....
That ends up not evaluating to true, no matter if I use the CBUUID constant or the raw string of the UUID.

Comment: `service1` is a `CBService` UUID or a `CBCharacteristic` UUID? Log the  `characteristic.UUID` to be sure.

Comment: defined as: 
let service1 = CBUUID(string: "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
output from print(service1):  LOGGING SERVICES: 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E

Comment: FYI ... I don't have enough reputation points to chat, but can be emailed if you'd like to avoid the exceptionally long discussion here

Comment: print(" HOW MANY CHARS \(service.characteristics)") 
---- outputs ---- 
 HOW MANY CHARS Optional([<CBCharacteristic: 0x157e7b0a0, UUID = 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>, <CBCharacteristic: 0x157e3dc20, UUID = 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0x8, value = (null), notifying = NO>])

Comment: I"m an idiot. I figured out the UUID's were wrong. Sorry